# New User Rankings

Tags: feature-request, reputation, users, rankings

Right now one of the only real ranking in terms of overall performance on Stack Overflow (and related sites, obviously) is the reputation score. I know there are also some rankings per tag, but I am looking for possibilities for new types of user rankings based on other criteria.

Some examples:

- Most prolific question asking
- Most prolific answering
- Greatest answer-to-question ratio
- Highest average question score (with at least X questions)
- Highest average answer score (with at least X answers)
- Most accepted answers
- Accepted vs. total answers ratio

I would never expect that all of these would ever be implemented, but I am interested in knowing what would be the most popular options or what other potential options for user ranking there are.

Comment: Welbog is going to laser you sooo hard.

Comment: @Rich B:    What

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't this be possible with the data dumps? Does it need to be real time?

Comment: With the data dumps you could do pretty much everything you want with the data dumps, but I would imagine most would want something a little more expedient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sort of against these features. It seems way too game like. And there are also some possibilities for gaming, for example, I could keep creating creating a new account for each answer I post, until I got one accepted, and then I would have 100% accepted answers! Obviously, you could put in restrictions like you must have more than 500 rep (arbitrary, could be anything), but that seems kind of unfair (and the people who do well in these rankings would just be the very high rep users).

Comment: Most of the high-rep users do not ask many questions and answer a lot.

Comment: Zifre: I should have probably noted on the ratio one as well that it would require X amount of questions and/or answers to qualify for that. Sorry if that was unclear.