# User ranking on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, rankings

In addition to showing reputation scores, SO should rank users. In the users section, users are ordered by the reputations they have.

Each user should also have a unique rank, since many users can have the same reputation score.

Rank must follow the order laid out by reputation, but for those having similar reputation, an additional formula should be defined which can rank users based on tags, time since registration, frequency of activity and/or helpfulness of their answers.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

People get too excited by the reputation / position. Just post good questions / answers

"lo que será, será"

Comment: Of course it's easy for *us* to say that... though I quite agree.

Comment: ranking would just be another motivating factor...but I agree with you..

Comment: "lo que será, será"

Comment: pasara lo que tenga que pasar... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the ordinal rank and percentile of all users on stack exchange [**here**](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573)

You can get your rank and percentile on custom flair [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1578/sorep-v2-ranked-flair-take-2)

You can show off as many of your accounts as you like

---

[image]

Comment: Site no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

[The reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) now maintains a list of relative rankings, on a per-weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly and all-time basis.

Answer (score 2):

I think reputation changes so quickly that this is not an issue. This can also be analyzed from the data dump if so inclined.

Comment: there are many users having same reputations. it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: At lower counts there are a lot of common scores, but this rapidly stops happening with even a few hundred rep.

Comment: (looks forward to the time when I need a time-breaker with Jon... as if...)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really an issue, but you could introduce a tie-breaker based on badges, e.g. have a "score from badges" of 25 * gold + 10 * silver + bronze. Then if the users are *still* tied, go for "higher user id wins" (as they've accrued the same score in a shorter time).

But no, I don't think this is worth doing :)

Comment: I struggle to think of a time when it would be needed...

Comment: "needed"? Well the whole scoring thing isn't needed, but it gets people to think of SO like a game and get answering questions to get points. It's what drives the site, and some kind of "User Rank" would help do that. I'm suggesting a different system here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/user-rank-or-user-percentile-rating

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a duplicate of my own suggestion for different user ranking metrics.

[New User Rankings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/new-user-rankings)

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is an API to grab minor stats such as rep per language, rep
   per answer, most changed answers, etc. that'd be of major interest
   to people like me who'd like to study the truth behind the numbers. **(Update: looks like https://data.stackexchange.com/ will help satiate my hunger for data)**
2. I agree that in a vacuum rank is not a clear indicator of
   excellence. However, there could be a way to quantitatively
   demonstrate value to interested parties such as clients, based on
   your particular field. There could be a per-language leaderboard
   that's weighted on a score per answer basis. The reason being, C++,
   C#, JavaScript Q&A has a distinct advantage over many other
   languages. The current state is analog to an English language tutor
   competing with a Tongan language tutor for world-wide job interest.

Answer (score 0):

Following link will give you the answer:

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)