# Where am I amongst all SO users?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User ranking on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/user-ranking-on-stack-overflow)

On Stack Overflow, When we click on **`Users`** button given besides Tags and Badges, it will shows a list of all the users (Sorted in the order of Higher to Lower Repulation).

[image]

You can see in above image, currently Jon Skeet is at 1<sup>st</sup>, Marc Gravell is at 2<sup>nd</sup>, and so on. So I would also eager and excited to know my Rank amongst all the SO users, there should be a ranking facility. Isn't there ?

My profile is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/pm-paresh-mayani

Comment: I found this: http://stackusers.com/Users/Find , its easy to find my rank on all my associated account

Comment: here is an already this feature available by StackExchange itself: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

Comment: Its really bad , i have just noticed that someone is downvoted, but this question was asked before SO has invented "User Reputation League" so what do you think? It should be appreciated or make unhappy to bug/feature submittor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just execute this query.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/312/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile

Entering your **userid** shows your rank **4958**

you can also see rank here, just enter your name

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

Comment: (Could be up to two months old...)

Comment: +1 helpful, but @Benjol's comment says its two months old

Comment: here is an already this feature available by StackExchange itself: stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there's a quick way to find yourself on the list, but it's pretty easy to find yourself manually. You're currently in the last spot on [page 136](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=136&tab=reputation). Since there are 35 people per page, that makes you 4760th

Comment: ya its exactly, but i suggest one thing that badge should be displayed with Rank, isn't it? For e.g. 1 Jon Skeet, 2 Marc ,and so on

Answer (score 2):

Easy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

More seriously, yes this is an *interesting* statistic, but I'm not sure that it's a very userful one. The long tail is so long, that being the 4760th user could be construed as very good (as a percentage of the total), but what do you make of all the 1-rep-never-came-back users?

Come back when you're on page 1 :)

Comment: If you're on page 1 it's pretty easy to tell what position you're in...

Comment: i am now at stackoverflow.com/users?page=135&tab=reputation , and as @amelvin's comment i am included Top 2% :)

Answer (score 2):

Your rep is currently 2814, overall position (135 * 35) + 21 = #4746

There is clearly a long tail in terms of reputation as 90% of SO users have less than 250 reputation.  So I would suggest that a reasonable initial target for most people interested in using the site regularly would be enough reputation to be in the top 1% of registered users.

Given that there are 9,523 pages of registered users (almost exactly a third of a million) you are currently just outside the top 1% of registered users in terms of reputation.

Current (Approximate) Reputation Milestones:

- Top 10%: 250 or better
- Top 5%: 720 or better
- Top 2%: 2040 or better
- Top 1%: 3850 or better
- Top 0.1%: 22,000 or better
- Top Page: 80,000 or better

You can select the page you are on, goto 'Users', click 'next' and adjust the 'Page' in the querystring until you find your rep. https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=136&tab=reputation

Comment: +1 helpful information, how do you calculate this "Current (Approximate) Reputation milestones?"

Comment: I am now at http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=135&tab=reputation

Comment: @Paresh The Milestones are simply based on the reputation of who is currently around that many percent from the top.  So The 1% milestone is currently the reputation of someone on Page 96 of the list (as there are 9,541 pages of registered users) - about the #3,331st ranked person.  The milestones change over time, although I would guess the bottom 90% will stick around 250 reputation, the more rarefied atmosphere at the top will keep on getting thinner.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just select the page you are on but the yearly rep leages should give you a juff on how many pages you are down.

So if say for example you are coming 45th then you would be on page 3.

Hope you find where you are.

Comment: You can select the page you are on, goto 'Users', click 'next' and adjust the 'Page' in the querystring until you find your rep.  I'm on page 172 http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=172&tab=reputation

Comment: @amelvin i am now at stackoverflow.com/users?page=135&tab=reputation