# User Rank -or- User Percentile Rating

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-rank

It would be neat if you could see a users "User Rank" or "User Percentile Rating" within their profile. It could just be something like "Top 25%", "Within Top 250 Users", or "Rank: 4500 out of 6500 users", and would easily tell you where you rank based on score compared to all other users of SO.

This would increase the "game-iness" of SO, and would be another thing in addition to Score that would keep users wanting to increase their score. It would be like *"Man I only rank within the top 1500 users, damn I need to get my score up to be within the top 500. That's be awesome! Gotta go answer more questions."*

I know there's a similar request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/user-ranking-on-stackoverflow), but it's not the same as what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Top 25% would be a few hundred... Even top 95% is relatively easy to get.

Comment: Low rep users will want percentiles, and high rep users, the ranks; each looks better in that respective perspective.

Comment: top 95%? that only means oyu have to be in the !bottom 5% :)

Comment: mo an betta user stats here - http://stackapps.com/questions/1573

Answer (score 8):

I know that I personally (and some others) will judge our rank based on what page we are on in the user listing. After hitting a certain rep level, that is one of the few ways you can continue to strive towards high rep goals. "I wanna get up on page 2!"

**Edit**: You might also want to include a link to this older suggestion which proposes a number of new user rankings: [New User Rankings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/new-user-rankings)

Comment: The user page list is really annoying me. After not going to SO for more than a week, I've gone from page 10 to 11. I feel like I lost rep! (I actually gained about 20.) Rankings just makes the site feel way too game-ish.

Comment: You lose!!!! :)

Answer (score 8):

I am indexing ALL users on ALL sites [**HERE**](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573)

Answer (score 7):

I was going to ask for the same feature and I found this as a related question. I think it would be fun to have the following variables:

- Reputation
- Rank
- Percentile rank

With the following values available:

- Current
- Highest

Answer (score 4):

I second this, as you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/jon-skeet-badge/1708#1708).

Let's see: when Joel and Jeff say in the podcast that they get > 3'000'000 distinct hits with a world population of 9'000'000 programmers - taking into consideration that some will have multiple ip addresses to post from - we can estimate that 1/6 of all programmers are on SO.

If I am in the first 1.5% of all users on SO, does that means that i can savely say that I am in the top 10% worldwide? Or even the top 1.5%, as good programmers are on SO?

Comment: No, the best programmers are too busy to post much on SO. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/users/30436/larry-osterman.

Comment: I know that, but let me dream a little. It's just fun.

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to fine my rank, but since I am not Jon Skeet or Marc Gravell it involves a lot of clicking through pages for me. Since I started learning Python I typed together a little script which would do the clicking for me. If you are a low reputation user like I am, it takes quiet a while. When asked for user id, type in the number from the url when going on your profile

```
                                 |
                                 v    
http://stackoverflow.com/users/74660/lucas
```

Enjoy:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class UserParser(HTMLParser):
    counter = 0
    userid = 0
    result = 0
    found = False 
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                m = re.search('^/users/(\d+)/(.*)',value)
                if name == 'href' and  m:
                    self.counter = self.counter + 1
                    if 0 == self.counter%2:
                        string = str(self.counter//2)+ ':\t' + m.group(1) + '\t' + m.group(2)
                        if m.group(1) == str(self.userid):
                            self.found = True
                            self.result = self.counter//2
                        print(string)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
    parse = UserParser()
    parse.userid = input('Please enter your user id:')
    url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=" + str(1) 
    f = opener.open(url)
    content = f.read()
    i = 2
    parse.feed(content.decode("utf-8"))
    while (not parse.found):
        url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=" + str(i)      
        f = opener.open(url) 
        content = f.read()
        parse.feed(content.decode("utf-8"))
        i = i + 1
    print("********Found*********") 
    print(str(parse.userid) + " found at "+ str(parse.result))
```

Not exactly pretty but it works good enough for me ... (I have low standards)

Comment: Lucas, you don't need to do this any more. I am indexing for everyone here http://skysanders.net/tools/sorep/default.aspx  see this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43911/trilogy-site-ranking-for-those-who-need-to-know

Answer (score 2):

This is completed through the Stack Exchange user leagues:

> https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Blog post with details

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/

Screenshot of it in action on http://gaming.stackexchange.com

[image: stack exchange user leagues]

Comment: Is there a way to see the percentage?

Answer (score -2):

I like the numeric ranks.

I think named ranks would work too, but I can't really come up with suitable ones that I like other than **Newbie**, **Student** and **Freshman** (these aren't meant to be programming specific)

I was thinking something like

```
Newbie        1-500
Student     500-1k
Freshman     1k-5k
Graduate     5k-20k
```

Comment: If you're serious about this (and perhaps want to put a bit more thought into it to flesh it out - for example, reputation on Stack Overflow goes well above 20k), I suggest posting this as a separate feature request.

Comment: @AnnaLear Of course I like this idea.  Given this initial negative response however, I don't see a point in extending this./