# Easy Way to find out what your user rank is?

Tags: feature-request, users, user-accounts, rankings, user-rank

Is there an easy way to find out what your user rank is?  If not it would be nice to have that feature.

I can go to the users tab and find out what page I am on (96) and  multiply that by 35 (users per page) and then subtract my location on the page (12) to get my user rank (3,348)

Not that rank is that important, but it is fun to know.  Is there an easier way or if not can a way be made?

Comment: There are 35 users per page.

Comment: I always thought it would be nice to have as a percentile (i.e. top 0.12% of users).

Comment: @Robert that wouldn't be that useful. As there are a lot of users with 1 rep point, and they occasionally get culled after they have been inactive for a given amount of time.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/user-rank-or-user-percentile-rating

Comment: find your ordinal rank and percentile here http://stackapps.com/questions/1573/stackusers-com-all-users-all-the-time

Answer (score 8):

If you are ranked high enough you will appear in this list:

http://so.chrisballance.com/

It shows the top 1,015.  You have to be above 7,943 rep to be in that list.

Comment: Cool site.  I guess I need to get more req so I can get on that list.

Comment: @Vaccano Yeah, you will have to work a bit harder if you want a really easy way to track your rank.

Comment: I'm #491! I'm #491! I'm #491! w00t! IN YOUR FACE #492!!!

Comment: "One forty-one could post faster than he, but @Jon B was looking for one forty-three..."

Comment: @mmy, brilliant poem...what does it mean?

Comment: @jjnguy: It's from an old, very silly song. http://www.google.com/search?q=the+ballad+of+irving

Answer (score 2):

> I can go to the users tab and find out what page I am on (96) and multiply that by 36 (users per page) and then subtract my location on the page (12) to get my user rank (3,348)

Actually, the correct formula is users per page * (pagenum-1) + position:  35 * (96-1) + 12 = 3337.

Comment: Thanks.  Sure would be nice to not have to do the math myself though....

Comment: @Æther: AFAIK, unregistered users are not listed in the default order by reputation view. This can skew the result a little bit--especially for low rep users.

Comment: It's easier when your on the front page ;-)

Comment: @Fearless/Mehrdad: hmm, I wonder how far up the rep list you have to go to find the top unregistered user. I can't recall seeing an "unknown" higher than ~300.

Comment: @Æther: I think you can change your display name even if you are unregistered (= cookie account). I believe, as you said, most accounts that matter are registered. Just wanted to point out this not obvious fact.

Answer (score 1):

Another different view of the user rankings is here: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/users/

Currently I've only run the query for users with >10k reputation. But it shows a lot more stats (and per-tag for each user, too) than just reputation.

How's *your* answer accept rate?

Comment: Nice work.  Found out I had an accepted answer for [java]!  Thankfully it was mistagged and I could remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 1st:

http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx?qid=1699

Comment: Very nice!  Holding steady at 68.  It's been a long time since I was on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

I am indexing all users on all sites here: [StackUsers.com - everything you ever wanted to know but were afraid to ask. (about an SE user. almost.)](https://stackapps.com/questions/1573/stackusers-com-all-users-all-the-time)