# Would it be useful to show people's "hit rate" - i.e. percentage of answers accepted?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer

Just out of idle curiosity I thought I'd check how many of my answers had been accepted. The only way I could see was to manually count.

Would people be interested in seeing this as a statistic on the profile page?

BTW - mine's about 11% (28 ish / 264) - it's ish because I gave up counting and didn't want to count my answers to my questions that I'd accepted.

NOTE: This is not the same as the <strike>current</strike> now removed "Accept Rate" - i.e. how many questions have accepted answers.

Comment: You're rocking it up the charts at 71% on Meta now.

Comment: @jeff: I don't think that's not what OP meant. **What is the percentage of provided answers has been accepted?** And it seems like it's a number from SO, not meta.

Comment: Yeah, the number of a user's questions for which they have accepted any answer seems like a less useful measure of how much that user contributes to SO.

Comment: Okay, this just convinced me that showing the accept rate is a good thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318311

Comment: That definitely is a user of the system right there.

Comment: I've previously requested statistics/badges for accepted answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/display-statistics-have-subject-badges-for-accepted-answers

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of showing how many of my questions have accepted answers.

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, here's some top answerer data from the last dump:

#### User                      Answers Accepted percent

```
Jon Skeet                 4787    1945     0.406   
Marc Gravell              3681    1330     0.361   
tvanfosson                2778    709      0.255   
Joel Coehoorn             2425    400      0.165   
JaredPar                  2086    564      0.270   
John Saunders             1977    317      0.160   
S.Lott                    1900    364      0.192   
Pax                       1584    332      0.210   
Neil Butterworth          1469    238      0.162   
Mehrdad                   1464    478      0.327   
VonC                      1427    417      0.292   
Bill the Lizard           1418    184      0.130   
Greg Hewgill              1401    329      0.235   
Andrew Hare               1355    321      0.237   
Alex Martelli             1345    382      0.284   
Mitch Wheat               1336    283      0.212   
cletus                    1334    378      0.283   
Jonathan Leffler          1186    191      0.161   
litb                      1135    371      0.327   
duffymo                   1134    114      0.101   
Charlie Martin            1122    187      0.167   
Gumbo                     1075    301      0.280   
le dorfier                1071    83       0.077   
Tomalak                   1069    377      0.353   
Quassnoi                  1068    353      0.331   
Konrad Rudolph            1062    227      0.214   
CMS                       1043    272      0.261   
Steven A. Lowe            1027    101      0.098   
dirkgently                990     170      0.172   
chaos                     953     194      0.204   
Uri                       936     76       0.081   
Paolo Bergantino          924     493      0.534   
Vinko Vrsalovic           908     217      0.239   
Reed Copsey               908     263      0.290   
Greg                      907     293      0.323   
Mitchel Sellers           883     147      0.166   
AnthonyWJones             883     219      0.248   
FlySwat                   881     117      0.133   
Bill Karwin               878     307      0.350   
JP                        876     135      0.154   
Adam Rosenfield           875     216      0.247   
nickf                     853     141      0.165   
marc_s                    851     199      0.234   
1800 INFORMATION          846     151      0.178   
Tom Hawtin - tackline     845     153      0.181   
Paul Tomblin              843     119      0.141   
Lasse V. Karlsen          836     163      0.195   
annakata                  831     114      0.137   
Aaron Digulla             823     127      0.154   
bobince                   810     225      0.278   
Gamecat                   793     82       0.103   
Michael Burr              791     175      0.221   
leppie                    786     115      0.146   
Norman Ramsey             782     91       0.116   
Will                      779     136      0.175   
Robert Harvey             771     132      0.171   
Ólafur Waage              771     95       0.123   
Cade Roux                 770     122      0.158   
kgiannakakis              764     140      0.183   
Adam Davis                759     144      0.190   
HLGEM                     755     49       0.065   
unwind                    743     135      0.182   
Guffa                     735     178      0.242   
Jason Baker               733     40       0.055   
Brian Agnew               733     143      0.195   
James Curran              726     77       0.106   
Henk Holterman            723     123      0.170   
Brian R. Bondy            722     192      0.266   
Josh                      713     143      0.201   
vartec                    709     140      0.197   
Earwicker                 706     110      0.156   
Michael Borgwardt         705     102      0.145   
jalf                      699     144      0.206   
JB King                   696     34       0.049   
Robert Gould              694     38       0.055   
ChrisW                    693     91       0.131   
Masi                      683     14       0.020   
ocdecio                   680     91       0.134   
gbn                       675     152      0.225   
Thomas Owens              674     27       0.040   
PhiLho                    664     70       0.105   
ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells 661     117      0.177   
Kibbee                    658     58       0.088   
Paul Dixon                637     181      0.284   
Michael Stum              636     86       0.135   
Gishu                     621     91       0.147   
MSalters                  619     66       0.107   
aku                       616     109      0.177   
erickson                  613     195      0.318   
Anton Gogolev             612     117      0.191   
unknown                   612     69       0.113   
Kev                       610     137      0.225   
Daok                      608     72       0.118   
Fredrik Mörk              607     153      0.252   
TheTXI                    604     105      0.174   
Matthew Flaschen          603     135      0.224   
casperOne                 603     172      0.285   
Galwegian                 602     85       0.141   
David B                   602     126      0.209   
Noldorin                  592     160      0.270
```

Here is **top 100** for ordered by ratio (for people who answered more than 50 questions)

#### User                  Answers Accepted percent

```
rq                    68      40       0.588   
Daniel LeCheminant    202     115      0.569   
Ayman                 162     92       0.568   
molf                  123     69       0.561   
rmoore                107     58       0.542   
Paolo Bergantino      924     493      0.534   
José Basilio          360     180      0.500   
Miles                 99      49       0.495   
Eric Rosenberger      58      28       0.483   
Jason Coco            203     97       0.478   
Justin Cave           114     54       0.474   
Ben Gottlieb          226     107      0.473   
Gdeglin               72      34       0.472   
Steef                 51      24       0.471   
Martin Woodward       134     63       0.470   
Ahmad Mageed          58      27       0.466   
Moff                  58      27       0.466   
Alconja               70      32       0.457   
jason                 57      26       0.456   
Jesse Rusak           77      35       0.455   
Perspx                97      44       0.454   
Nicholas Riley        84      38       0.452   
Jim Dovey             71      32       0.451   
Greg Campbell         59      26       0.441   
Borgar                64      28       0.438   
ChrisN                135     59       0.437   
Alex James            85      37       0.435   
mdb                   92      40       0.435   
Owen                  209     91       0.435   
Yehuda Katz           62      27       0.435   
mercator              63      27       0.429   
Robert Macnee         94      40       0.426   
Reto Meier            54      23       0.426   
Stuart Childs         99      42       0.424   
Jarret Hardie         236     100      0.424   
Joel Spolsky          64      27       0.422   
Ron DeVera            60      25       0.417   
ShreevatsaR           101     42       0.416   
Magnar                56      23       0.411   
Vlad Romascanu        192     79       0.411   
Godeke                110     45       0.409   
Jon Skeet             4787    1945     0.406   
insin                 121     49       0.405   
mghie                 262     106      0.405   
smorgan               89      36       0.404   
Panos                 114     46       0.404   
ybo                   77      31       0.403   
hasseg                92      37       0.402   
James Gregory         92      37       0.402   
Craig Stuntz          538     216      0.401   
Martin Harris         140     56       0.400   
ChssPly76             120     48       0.400   
Steven Lyons          63      25       0.397   
msaeed                58      23       0.397   
unknown               58      23       0.397   
Christopher_G_Lewis   61      24       0.393   
Matt Hamilton         547     215      0.393   
Ted Naleid            64      25       0.391   
Shog9                 432     169      0.391   
Stephen Martin        64      25       0.391   
Josh G                90      35       0.389   
Anton Tykhyy          57      22       0.386   
Aziz                  57      22       0.386   
Ben M                 68      26       0.382   
Kent Boogaart         568     217      0.382   
Sean Bright           202     77       0.381   
nosklo                291     111      0.381   
keparo                71      27       0.380   
Steve Willcock        137     52       0.380   
Denis Troller         143     54       0.378   
Rob Conery            141     53       0.376   
Branden Hall          72      27       0.375   
itowlson              80      30       0.375   
unknown               56      21       0.375   
Carl Meyer            155     58       0.374   
eu-ge-ne              220     82       0.373   
Louis Gerbarg         227     84       0.370   
Andrew Moore          187     69       0.369   
Milan Novota          95      35       0.368   
Jason                 68      25       0.368   
Scott Hanselman       68      25       0.368   
Steve K               77      28       0.364   
Rob Mensching         77      28       0.364   
NeARAZ                58      21       0.362   
Michael S. Scherotter 69      25       0.362   
Rick Copeland         61      22       0.361   
Marc Gravell          3681    1330     0.361   
Simon Lieschke        75      27       0.360   
htw                   89      32       0.360   
Ashley Clark          53      19       0.358   
back2dos              137     49       0.358   
maxnk                 53      19       0.358   
Michael               297     106      0.357   
gcores                87      31       0.356   
weppos                155     55       0.355   
Pesto                 217     77       0.355   
hop                   82      29       0.354   
Ed Harper             79      28       0.354   
Nadia                 150     53       0.353   
Pourquoi Litytestdata 51      18       0.353
```

Here is the query if you're curious:

```
select
    uuser.id,
    uuser.displayname,
    count(post.id) as ans,
    count(vote.id) as acc,
    1.0*count(vote.id)/count(post.id) as pct
from uuser
        join post on (uuser.id = post.owneruserid)
        left join vote on (vote.postid = post.id)
    and post.posttypeid = 2
    and vote.votetypeid = 1
    group by uuser.id, uuser.displayname
    order by ans desc;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right - how come I'm not in that list? I've got 500+ accepted answers. Or is it sorting by total answers?

Comment: @Paolo: it is ordered by total answers (note the order by ans desc on the bottom line).

Comment: @Paolo: yeah it's ordered by total answers. I did notice you had an excellent ratio though, higher than Jon Skeet! I've updated the table.

Comment: @Greg: What about another table sorted by the accept ration descending.

Comment: A great many people had a 100% ratio from a single answer which was accepted. Some people had up to a dozen or so answers which were also all accepted. It wasn't obvious to me how many answers were needed before the stats became "interesting".

Comment: @Greg: Ah, that's understandable. What about ordering by the total number of accepted answers per user? (I'd do this myself, but I don't have a SQL version of the latest dump)

Comment: @Greg, your answer has been spShog9d, remember to vote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248764/formatting-link-lists-using-tsql up if you find this useful

Answer (score 7):

This is possible using the advanced search options.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

try searching for

> user:me isaccepted:1

Comment: It's only possible up to a point (with that point being 1,000). It just says 1,000+ search results rather than the actual number beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great stat. Also what would be good at a glance is a ratio of Questions to Answers--identify who's and asker and who's an answerer.

There should be a threshold, though.  I think that if you don't have a "minimum answers" thing, you'll get a huge skew of folks who have only answered one question. Sort of like when the do all the awards at the end of an NHL season--there's always a minimum number of games played for best save percentage. Otherwise, some minor league goalie who was in for five shutout minutes would win every year.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up slightly stale data on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). [Accepted Answer Statistics (II)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1396/accepted-answer-statistics-ii) shows how many accepted answers you have. To see the most accepted users, look at [Top users by accept answer rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/963/top-users-by-accept-answer-rate).

Comment: I'll repeat my comment from a now deleted answer - Thanks for the info and links. I knew I should have put that I knew the stats could be got from the data dump ;).

Answer (score 1):

That was actually one of the rankings I was suggesting here: [New User Rankings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/new-user-rankings)

I think it would be an interesting metric, but it will almost always be skewed towards people with a lower answer count.

Comment: *better answers.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. You can suggest this question is closed as a dupe if you like.

Comment: ChrisF: Yours is different in that you are suggesting it on the profile page while mine was a suggestion for it used as a way of ranking people on the user page. I don't think it's necessary to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: OK - cheers. I've actually voted to close myself (would be nice if I could revoke that!) but won't be too upset if it actually gets closed.

Comment: I've just checked my stats from the link provided by @dbr and I can see @TheTXI's point about skewing towards lower answer count. In one tag I've got a 100% hit rate but I've only answered one question! Perhaps there needs to be a minimum number of answers before this stat is displayed. Then it might also encourage people to answer more!

Comment: ChrisF: For rankings I definitely agree for a minimum post count, but still the stat will always skew towards lower post counts because every question you answer that is not accepted hurts you ratio further and further.