# Add a 'Skeet Sniped' badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

For fun:

Answered a question first with at least one upvote, but Jon Skeet eventually receives the accepted answer.

**EDIT:**

I changed the title so as not to have Jon's name tainted with such a [horrible double meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Get+skeeted+on). I had no idea such a term existed...

Comment: I swear this is a dupe oddly enough.

Comment: Too funny, but "first with at least one upvote" is too easy.  Maybe be the accepted answer, until JS shows up, and it's given to him.  Or your answer outvotes JS's but he still gets the accepted answer.

Comment: The dupe is the opposite, *beating the skeet*

Comment: This is the worst possible naming. I am not sure you understand the alternate meaning, but I encourage you to look it up before recommending this kind of stuff.

Comment: Looked it up... very bad indeed. [I apologize Mr. Skeet]

@Rich B: Look it up! How in heck am I supposed to know about something like that?!?

Comment: If you're serious, rather than single out Jon Skeet perhaps any person with the greater of your rep + 10K or your rep x 2?

Comment: @Josh, watch Chris Rock ... its a window into an alternate reality

Comment: Hmmm, the only badge that Jon Skeet wouldn't have.

Comment: Ah, possible duplicate/variation on this question:  'Badge Suggestion: beat-the-skeet" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9060/badge-suggestion-beat-the-skeet

Comment: I sympathize with Josh ... I had no idea what that meant either. ... wish I still didn't.

Answer (score 6):

I was recently thinking that a Skeeting / being Skeeted would be where you see a question, think "I know the answer", go to reply and promptly scream "**DAMN YOU JON SKEET, DO YOU EVER SLEEP?**"

Comment: I have a somewhat different definition of *being skeeted* , and it aint pretty.

Comment: and now I need a cheese grater for my head.  Thanks @Ian Elliott

Comment: Seriously though, how did such a term come into existence?!? Who was the person to think "It shall be called skeeting" WHY???

Comment: @Josh, ignorance is bliss

Answer (score 3):

Similar version for SF, replacing Jon Skeet with Evan Anderson

Comment: +1 - The first comparison to Jon Skeet that I've seen for myself. I love it.  >smile<

Answer (score 2):

I suggested something similar but think I may have deleted it.  I didn't want the "Skeeted" reference to take away from the positive of what Jon does...  It happens frequently when a higher rep person answers a question later and ends up getting more up votes and the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think these "fun" badges are best left for data-dump analysis, we can determine most of this from the data dump anyway, and even though Jon has a phenomenal [hit rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep/16633#16633) some other users have higher ones.