# Hide reputation of people answering

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/hide-the-rep-and-badge-count-on-a-users-info-box-on-answers)

I think that the OPs tend to accept answers of people with large reputations. 
At the same time people in general tend to favor answers of people with large reputations even thought there are similar, identical or even better answers from people with a smaller reputation.

Wouldn't hiding the reputation of all the answerers be a good idea ?

Comment: Might the answers of those users with a high reputation not simply be good?

Comment: "I think that the OPs tend to accept answers of people with large reputations." - Do you have any evidence of this? I've never had any trouble beating people with higher rep - even when I first joined SO.

Comment: I think you will find most people with high reputation are held to a higher standard than those will little reputation.

Comment: I think if anything I'm more critical of people with high rep answering my question.  I think if someone with less rep gave an equally helpful answer I would gravitate more to accepting the lower rep user's answer.

Comment: Why?  I want *everyone* to know how enlightened and deserving of upvotes I am when I post answers, goddammit.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, you can't really provide examples.  You can't *know* why someone upvoted one person over another.  You could think it was because of content, I could think it was because of rep.  The fact that high rep users do/don't end up with more upvotes on a question than low rep users doesn't tell us *why*.

Comment: @Servy: An example would be, for instance, a link to a question where a better answer was posted by someone with lower rep but it did not get reognized.

Comment: I've had the OP write "Thanks for your answer, but I'm accepting the other answer because you don't need the points." or something similar. So I think it goes both ways.

Comment: @WesleyMurch That doesn't tell us *why* the better answer wasn't upvoted.  Other possible reasons are: 1. it was posted later, and upvotes snowball 2. the "better" answer was different, rather than common boilerplate code, so readers were unfamiliar with it.  Someone may upvote an answer they knew worked over something they haven't ever seen that seemed "cool", even if it was faster/shorter/whatever.

Comment: FWIW I don't even bother to look at the box with the person's name in it. I agree with the **premise** of this suggestion. I care solely about the content of the answer to a question; I decide how good the answer is by trying the solution for myself, not by how much the community "trusts" the person answering. The contributions of an active user, of a new user, and of a lurker deserve equal attention. While this suggestion makes sense (and I upvoted it for that), I just don't care because the change wouldn't affect me. If people want to see someone's rep at a glance, that's a feature for them.

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons why we have reputations is so that people whose answers are usually good can be visibly recognised. If this means that it helps a questioner to choose between several answers, that's a *good* thing.

In practice, I think people tend to accept the answer that actually worked for them, rather than the answer that was posted by the person with the highest rep.