# Is there any way to hide my badges and reputation from others?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, badges

I ask because I believe badges and reputation serve only in creating implicit bias amongst askers when viewing answers and comments, and on the flip-side amongst commenters and answerers when viewing questions. This can lead to a dubious framing and misrepresented view of users in general. People should not be judged on these. They should be judged based on the quality of their posts, not meaningless accolades. To be blunt, in my opinion it's all very stupid, and I want to mitigate this stupidity is much as possible. Any solutions?

At first my question may seem to be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-avatar-badges-and-reputation) or [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/hide-the-rep-and-badge-count-on-a-users-info-box-on-answers). However (unless I am mistaken) these posts both refer to preventing yourself from viewing your own/other users's badges and reputation info when viewing questions and answers . What I want however, is to **hide my badges and reputation **from others****. Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "no" - there's no real way to hide your badges and reputation. While I get the sentiment, *broadly* reputation and badges are part of the 'core' model of the network. We're gamified top to bottom. What you can do is tied into both reputation and badges to various levels.

In a sense you 'know' you can trust me because I've nearly 150k rep here and I've a gold badge in say [support](/questions/tagged/support). Even without being a moderator  - most of the things I can do now as an appointed or elected moderator are available to me (at least in part) cause I'm a high rep user. I can dupe close certain tags cause I have a diamond there. Reputation and badges are *intrinsic* to the system

> This can lead to a dubious framing and misrepresented view of users in general. People should not be judged on these. They should be judged based on the quality of their posts, not meaningless accolades.

Well yes, you can read those. And I'd argue that as a moderator, and someone who makes lots of typos that get fixed, that *does* happen. People do read and judge my posts. I'm pretty sure if I broke a rule though, I'd get called out.

If you 'like' the content on SE - its generated, at least to an extent, because there's something that provides intrinsic and extrinsic motivation. At least to some - those numbers on top of the page, and under your posts *are* extrinsic motivation and at least for some, the reason they post, or at least pop by regularly. Its going to be weird if some folks decide "I do not wish to associate myself with the reputation and badge system". We'd have folks doing things as designed, and folks pretending they don't exist.

If you don't want to worry about the badge system, reputation and such, just don't. There's nothing wrong with focusing on quality content. Read and upvote the good stuff. I like to go down research rabbitholes occasionally.

Fundamentally its something unlikely to happen - well short of someone in management being completely tonedeaf, and pushing it through cause they think its a good idea.

Comment: Since rep is acquired through more than just providing answers, the fact is I have no way of knowing if your reputation is representative of the quality/accuracy of your information, and the credibility of your sources, or if you merely play the "game" consistently. It says nothing about what lengths you went to in order to acquire or provide this information. The upvotes system is broken since there's no real way for me to know if an upvoted answer from you is actually right or just believed to be right because people assume so base on your rep.

Comment: My posts are quite literally matter of public record. A good many of them, especially on super user are testable. You're free and capable of auditing my posts on their own merits as you can anyone's

Comment: The way you describe reputation and badges in the answer you gave makes it seem so entirely dogmatic. It's like... "Trust me, look at my score, my way is the right way, have faith in my high reputation" as if you're a higher rank in the faith chain. A cardinal above priests above the congregation. In reality though I don't know whether I can trust you or anybody on stack exchange for that matter, because reputation says nothing about integrity, and sinve there are gaming rewards I will always have to question the motivations behind actions of SE users.

Comment: If I was able to address these concerns myself I would already know the hypothetical information I'd be looking to acquire, and therefore wouldn't need to verify whether your information was correct or not to begin with. Not showing badges or reputation seems to work out fine on mathoverflow from what I understand, there's no reason it wouldn't work fine here, and in my opinion it would weed out people who are just here to interact just for the sake of interacting and  playing game the game as opposed to providing/seeking information.

Comment: And what I mean by "address these concerns" is that if I was informed wnough to properly and correctly audit anyone's posts (yours or otherwise) I wouldn't hve need to be informed by said post in the first place