# Can we add an "Average Score" to each user's info?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a rep “batting average”? (similar to the questioner’s accept rate)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/add-a-rep-batting-average-similar-to-the-questioners-accept-rate)

I think it would be intersting to see an alternate way to order users on the users page.

In the same manner that you can order answers and questions on a tab-like interface with

[ Oldest | Newest | Votes ]

We could have a simlar tab on the users page [ Reputation | Avg Score ]

Just as an example, looking at the top two users, Jon Skeet and Mark Gravell:

Skeet: (21 Questions + 9020 Answers) / 197,990 Rep = 21.89 Avg score

Gravell: (21 Questions + 5682 Answers / 155,513 = 27.26 Avg Score

And already we have the list changing order based on the new metric.

I think this would help showcase some of the users who may be newer and/or don't rack up rep by sheer volume (not saying that Skeet's posts aren't of high quality, but the dude has a serious mass of posts on SO)

Instead of "Average Score" we could call it "Rep per post", "Quality Rating" or some other suitable name.

This could have the added benifit of discouraging me-too or junk posts.

Comment: You aren't taking vote counts into consideration.

Comment: @balus Also not taking bounties into consideration. Not taking 'downvotes-given', nor '100 point spam penalty', nor the rep-reward difference for questions vs answers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think average score is relevant to a user's reputation. Reputation is a measure of your contribution to the site. It's a strange animal. It's not a measure of quality or of quantity.

The biggest problem I see with average score is that broadly appealing questions tend to get more views and higher scores. Some users take the time to post high-quality answers to obscure questions. These users would be penalized by an average score ranking.

Comment: "I don't think average score is relevant to a user's reputation" it's not, it's something DIFFERENT, which is the point. "broadly appealing questions tend to get more views and higher scores. Some users take the time to post high-quality answers to obscure questions. These users would be penalized by an average score ranking." You're assuming having a low average is a "penalty" or that the slow rep growth from obscure questions isnt already an issue of rep itself.

Comment: @Neil If two posters have a different average post score, one higher and one lower, how am I to judge them based on only that information. If you say "Well, you can't really know anything about them from just that number", then why display it?

Comment: @Neil - yes, it's something different. Another way to state my case would be to simply say that I don't think average score has any real value.

Comment: @devinb, i didnt know you "judged" users. Do you judge them on rep?

Comment: @Neil - it might, however, be interesting to devise an algorithm that took into consideration page views and number of answers. That would give you an idea of how someone faired based on how many votes they _could_ have had, and how much competition there was.

Comment: @Neil - I think you mean that to be @devinb. But if you really want to know, I judge users by their MSO suggestions :P

Comment: well I DID do a search, and didn't find the dupe link posted above.

Comment: @Neil, Why provide information if I am *not* expected to use it in some manner ("make a judgement based on relevant information"). If you object to using the word 'judge' then change the sentence to, "How should their difference in average post rep affect my opinions about that user?"

Comment: @Neil - you mean you didn't search on "batting average"? tsk tsk. :)

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, since rep is a semi-useless metric, whats the harm in another, semi-useless metric?

Comment: @Neil, see my answer for the harm of this 'semi-useless' metric.

Answer (score 1):

This was fairly well covered on this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/add-a-rep-batting-average-similar-to-the-questioners-accept-rate/21352#21352)

My [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/add-a-rep-batting-average-similar-to-the-questioners-accept-rate/21352#21352) was as follows:

> Rep-per-answer is not a useful metric
>
> - There are people with many answers in niche tags who would have low rep-per-answer.
> - There are people who have many answers in very popular tags who aren't fast enough to get huge upvotes.
> - There are people who answer very few questions, but answer them very very thoroughly and get huge upvotes.
> - There are people who only answer joke-type questions and get huge (undeserved) upvotes.
> - There are people who put off-the-cuff answers on a lot of questions and get a few upvotes.
>
> The point being that the rep-per-answer averages will vary wildly, but will not add any extra information about the user who is giving you the answer. Because rep is given out arbitrarily, there is not (and never has been) a way to firmly link rep-gain to usefulness.

Basically, reputation is based on a **huge** number of factors and only one of them is skill.

### **EDIT**

In response to comment:

> "Basically, reputation is based on a huge number of factors and only one of them is skill." True, and so could the average. If you want to take into account downvotes given, bounties given, etc, then why not? The rep itself has lots of factors, why not the "avg"

In order for me to control (increase) my reputation, I need to invest more time in StackOverflow. This is very *beneficial* to the community.

In order for me to control (increase) my average-rep-per-post, I need to do one or more of the following things. (only a partial list)

- Delete my lower voted posts (even if they are still valid, or even checkmarked)
- Ignore any low-view tags or questions
- Create a sock-puppet user to upvote all my posts
- Downvote other users to make my posts look more attractive

You'll note that "write higher quality posts" is *not* on the list. There's a reason for that. Even a high quality post has a chance of **not** getting upvoted, which means it would *lower* my rep-average, and then I'd have to delete it. Also, "answer questions very quickly" is not on the list for the same reason.

Every item on that list is *not* a desirable behaviour.

Comment: Very true all !

Comment: "Basically, reputation is based on a huge number of factors and only one of them is skill."  True, and so could the average.  If you want to take into account downvotes given, bounties given, etc, then why not?  The rep itself has lots of factors, why not the "avg"

Comment: @Neil, I've responded

Comment: "Every item on that list is not a desirable behaviour"  I could also make a similar list of undesirable behaviours people use for the current Rep (some would be dupes of the ones you listed for an avg).  Does that make rep a bad idea?  Should we do away with it?

Comment: @Neil, you should make the list. :) We can't discuss it until you publicize it.

Comment: I can start with 3 of yours:
-Ignore any low-view tags or questions 
-Create a sock-puppet user to upvote all my posts 
-Downvote other users to make my posts look more attractive
These are already things people can do under the current system.  I dont see how an avg would increase any of these further than they already are.

Comment: @Neil, reputation is cumulative. If I post an answer that recieves 'only' one upvote, the result is *positive* on my overall rep and *negative* to my 'rep-per-post'. If I downvote all the posts around mine, I lose reputation. With reputation, there is no *negative* effect from posting a response that doesn't get upvotes.

Comment: @Neil, to quote a comment I made on the other Q. "Answering a niche question will ALWAYS bring down your avg"... but *never* bring down your rep.

Comment: And downvoting others doesn't bring down your rep?

Comment: @Neil, it does. "If I downvote all the posts around mine, I lose reputation."

Comment: And in turn, you would also lose average.  I'm not suggesting REPLACING rep with an average, only augmenting it.  you assuming people would suddenly stop caring about rep, they certainly won't.

Comment: If your "Average reputation" is simply "reputation / # posts" then it is *doubly* ridiculous. If I post one answer and get a 500 point bounty, it would say that I have a 500 avg. If then I offered a bounty, suddenly my reputation average would go down, even though none of my posts have been modified or changed in any way. I *assumed* you were going to do take "score of each post"/"Number of posts" which is at least an accurate representation of what it is called.

Comment: @Neil I'm not suggesting people will stop caring about rep, but I *am* saying that they WILL start caring about rep average. Probably care *more* about average than rep, because rep-average would **seem** to be a more accurate representation of their skill.

Comment: And my answer to that would be "So what?" user priveleges are stil based off rep.  Rep is what's displayed next to someones name...  If someone DOES care more about an average, or some type of computed rating, ... who cares? Do you care that some people obsess about rep while others couldn't care less?

Comment: @Neil. Maybe I missed something. "I think it would be intersting to see an alternate way to order users on the users page." **Why** do you want this feature? You've said "This could have the added benifit of discouraging me-too or junk posts." If you want to order posts based on this, you are saying it is a valid way to measure quality of a post. We can't order posts by reputation, because reputation isn't an indication of quality. Neither, as I've point out, is rep-per-post.

Comment: @Neil, additionally, if we are ordering by this, then there is a huge incentive to attempt to game the system. The post which is highest will tend to get the most upvotes. More upvotes gets more upvotes. This system would be self-fulfilling.

Comment: And the point you keep missing is, there is no more gaming the system incentive than there already is with the rep system.

Comment: I never suggested ordering POSTS by a users avg, that would be just as silly as ordering posts by users rep.  Posts are ordered by each post's up/down votes (or oldest/newest when a user chooses)

Comment: @Neil, I apologize, you are correct. I misread you (lol, I even *quoted* it!). And I disagree with "there is no more gaming incentive". Before, writing a post which was not your best work was still something to be rewarded for. You could gain *some* rep, and you were still helping stackoverflow by adding new information. With rep average, *every* post starts out as detrimental to my average. I start in the negative simply by posting anything at all. That is a *negative* consequence of what you suggest.

Comment: @Neil, before there was incentive to game just to gain reputation. But once your solution becomes implemented, then we need to game the system *always* simply to **maintain** the average I want. Once I get my average up high enough, there is not a *disincentive* to continue participating. With reputation, it can only go up, so there's never an *active* reason to stop.

Comment: @Neil, This was interesting but I'm done work and heading home. Thanks for a great discussion.

Comment: Popcorn, anyone?