# "Top Users" page should also list the people with the most accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, top-users

I am curious who has the most accepted answers for a topic.  Sometimes a lucky user will get +100 up votes on a single question,  but they are not an avid participant to that topic.

Comment: I am for this proposal.

Comment: I was pretty sure there was a more recent version of this, but [here's a similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25104/accepted-answers-count-on-tag-stats-page). Tag Stats are what they were called before it became Top Users. I should probably motion for a synonym...

Comment: Well, it could be argued that not always the accepted answer is the best one, so that metric isn't really reliable either. But unjustified accepts are certainly rarer than unjustified upvotes

Comment: I couldn't find a query on Data Explorer (thought it *had* to exist), so added it here for any who are curious: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15852/top-100-users-ranked-by-accepted-answers

Comment: @Nick - hehe, *lots* of rep in the salad days.  Hard to catch up with hard answers.  This one also makes you look really good: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/616/users-statistics-top-users  My compliments.