# Adjust ranking of top users for tags

Tags: discussion, top-users, rankings

The way users are ranked in 'Top Answerers' doesn't currently appear to accurately reflect user's contribution to a tag and it's questions. (Referring here to pages under https://stackoverflow.com/tags/[tag]/topusers) From how it appears to me, the ranking is mainly based on a ratio of tag-upvotes to questions answered, which penalises user's who answer many old/infrequently visited questions - which I'd imagine SO wants to be answered, for the sake of Googlers and the like.

I imagine this is more noticeable on the smaller tags, which are the majority of what I personally follow on SO - I'll illustrate with a couple of examples.

[image: opentbs rankings]

The all time answerers for [opentbs]. This struck me as odd today, as I saw I was above Sarah Kemp, who's answered many of my own questions, and is massively more knowledgable of the library than I am. Going into more detail, Sarah Kemp's 4 questions include 3, 0-voted accepted answers, and another with a score of one. Chris meanwhile, has provided a single (unaccepted) answer, which has a score of one. And as I understand the current system, that ranks Chris as a 'better answerer' for this tag?!?

Another example... (I was trying to avoid the vested interest of my own rankings, but this is the clearest example I can find.)

[image: jquery-token-input rankings]

The [jquery-token-input] tag. Here 'Chris' has answered a large number of questions under this tag, 2 of which have been accepted, yet 9/10 have received no upvotes. The situation here, is this is a library I've done a lot of work with recently, and as such, am fairly knowlegeable about the inner-workings of it. Because of this, I went through the tag and wrote answers to a number of older, cobweb-covered questions, which most likely were never seen by the original askers, but remain there for Google. However, due to the lack of upvotes, I'm ranked behind other users who've answered a single question on the tag.

I'm not suggesting upvotes are not a good reflection of an answerers ability, yet I think other factors should also be taken into consideration. In my opinion the ranking system would be improved if it takes the following factors into account more:

- No. of accepted answers
- Questions where the user's answer is the only answer, and there's been no further activity. (e.g. Original asker has not returned)
- More answers should have a positive effect on rankings, not negative (providing no downvotes and so.)

I'd be interested to know other peoples thoughts on the system, as I appreciate this reads like I have some serious vested interest! (I'm perfectly happy with the size of my...thanks.) But yes, it would also be interesting if an admin is able to provide the formula which is actually used for rankings here, from other examples it appears that it isn't just upvotes/answers which are taken into account...are question views included or something as well?

Comment: It appears you are operating in low-traffic tags, where there is a lot of noise and fewer votes. In higher traffic tags, these problems simply don't play.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with some of your suggestions; more answers on a question you've answered does _not_ make your answer better or make you (or me) a better answerer.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Valid. But more accepted answers?

Comment: The ranking on the `topusers` page is ranked solely on upvotes, the order for people with equal votes is arbitrary.

Comment: I guess it depends @Chris; it would be interesting to see what changes it makes in high vs. low volume tags. I'm not certain that I trust the OP but in high volume tags it should even out. In low volume you may skew ones you haven't included because they didn't demonstrate the same problem even more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Agreed this is more noticable in low-traffic tags. But if we improve the rankings here where we can 'see' better, surely that has the same effects on busier tags? And from what I can see, ranking on equal votes is highest position to most recent to achieve that upvote score. My point being that we have a wealth more of information to base a decision than just that!

Comment: @Chris: No, if there is any correlation between ranking and recency, then that's a side-effect of the database rows being entered later, I'd say. I doubt it is deliberate. Counter proof: the [`zodb` tag top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/zodb/topusers), I see at least 1 among those with 7 votes that answered less recently than someone ranked 'lower'. Same for those with 5 votes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Fair enough, must have been coincidence then. :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I've reconsidered my answer to your first comment, been pondering. I agree, more answers does not make you a better answerer, but I would say it makes it more likely that you are a BETTER answerer, rather than a WORSE one, as the current system seems to presume.