# Sort Answers on User Profile Page by Acceptance

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

There are many ways to sort through all the answers a user has given on their profile page... Recent, Views, Newest and Votes. However, especially when sorting on "Votes", it makes it hard to see overall which of your answers over time have been Accepted by others. It would be nice to have a way to sort answers so that all the "Accepted" answers are on top, with a secondary sort on Votes.

Also, and I'm sure this has been asked before, it would be nice to easily see what percentage of answers by a user have been accepted. This gives a good measure of the quality of their answers over time.

Comment: See here (just discovered this myself): http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: I was about to post a very similar suggestion. Good thing I searched first. I would definitely like to see this (the /search page is not obvious enough, nor quick enough for a casual glance)

Answer (score 4):

Although not on the profile page, you can get the desired results using a [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3ame%20isaccepted%3a1&tab=votes).  Search for:

```
user:me isaccepted:1
```

Then sort by votes.

As for the acceptance percentage, [see this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to do this via search. I'd still at least like to see the acceptance percentage be part of the profile page... just like you see the acceptance percentage of people who ask questions.