# Display the "Accepted as correct answer" rate

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be useful so show people's “hit rate” - i.e. percentage of answers accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep)

Some members have hundreds of answers, but only few are accepted as correct answers.
Some members have only few dozens of answers, but great part of them are accepted as correct.

In my opinion, this is important information, no less than the existing "Accept rate" displayed for every member asking a question.

So, such thing would be nice:
[image: My vision]

Comment: This does imply that a not accepted answer isn't a correct or helpful answer. While it's useful to see the `accept rate` to quickly determine if the user is giving any feedback, I don't see how this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer count is already taken into account in your reputation (there's a bonus equivalent to 1½ upvote for each accepted answer). I don't think it's a good idea to cutter up the answer signature with yet another number.

I also disagree with your formulation: an answer can be accepted even if incorrect, and (more commonly) can be correct but not accepted. (Are you saying that Pekka has a 20% incorrect answer rate?) This number should really be called “accepted answer rate”, or even “accept rate”¹.

It would make sense to show this statistic somewhere in the user profile.

There could be a tab in the [`/users`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) page too, with users (who have more than N answers in the time period shown) sorted by accepted answer rate. In the meantime, you can look up this number on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), e.g. [Top users by accept answer rate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/963/top-users-by-accept-answer-rate).

Comment: I have never heard of a bonus for each accepted answer; do you have a reference to a post on meta?

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's in the [faq#reputation]: answer is voted up = +10, answer is accepted = +15

Comment: I see; I thought you were referring to something else, such as a bonus for when your accepted answers are, e.g., 60% of the answers you have given. I guess _bonus_ confused me, as I don't consider the 15 points for an accepted answer a bonus. It's a bonus the 50 points extra you get when you register your email address on Area 51, or the 100 points you get when you reach a reputation of 200 in an SE site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't agree.

This rate would depend on users which decides to accept it or not, it means that when he post correct answer, but asking user would accept me, he would lose some percentage, but not reasonably.

So, I disagree!