# Show on user profile how many accepted answers one has given

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Pretty simple request:

I would like to see how many of the answers I have provided to others questions, have actually been accepted. I would also like to see this information on other users user page.

It could be as simple as saying ([for example for my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830035/ryan)):

**116 answers, 42 accepted answers**

A very old thread asking for this: [Would it be useful to show people's "hit rate" - i.e. percentage of answers accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-to-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-acce)

**EDIT 2**: This question has been marked as a duplicate of the above question. It's pretty much true that it is a duplicate. However the above question doesn't have an **ANSWER!**. It is still marked as a feature-request, not status-declined, not status-inprogress, it's just sitting there. Also it is 4 (almost 5 now) years old. Much of the info contained in it is very out of date.

If someone could comment on that old question as to whether or not this could be looked into: declined, planned, not going to happen till the Sun consumes the earth. Then I would be happy to leave this closed as a duplicate. Till that point I think it has a valid reason to stay open. Its a feature-request for a feature not implemented yet.

Another very old thread asking about this: [Display statistics/have subject badges for accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/display-statistics-have-subject-badges-for-accepted-answers/16062#16062)

Note that it also asks about badges. I don't care about badges I just want to see the acceptance rate of my answers.

Jeff Atwood also posted this search term that would show you your acceptance rate.

```
user:me isaccepted:1
```

Edit: Apparently this is not that hard to find, per Jim's comment

Finally it's a search term, and we are mostly programmers here, which means we are lazy. I don't want to search to see I have 42 accepted answers or that Jon Skeet has 14,729 accepted answers (holy crap this guy *is* a QA site by himself!). I want to just see it on my profile.

Comment: It's not that hard to find. There's a whole list of search tips on the search page.

Comment: @Jim doesn't change the facts about my last paragraph.