# Other Stats for the User Profile Page

Tags: feature-request, statistics

As requested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/add-acceptance-rate-to-the-user-profile-page/16638#16638) by Jeff, and discussed also in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2563/is-the-ratio-of-upvotes-to-downvotes-a-meaningful-measure-of-participation) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile/), here is an attempt at a comprehensive list of more statistics to show on the user profile page.

Note that I'm not necessarily saying that all of these need to be included, but I was hoping to give a good overview of stats that have been requested so far.  Maybe seeing lots of them in one place will inspire the developers to get some of them into production?

- **Accepted answer rate** -- as shown on your questions
- **Answer acceptance rate** -- how often your own answers are accepted
- **Number of accepted answers**
- **Ratio of answers-to-questions** -- how often this user helps others
- **Average question votes** -- average score for all questions
- **Average answer votes** -- average score for all answers
- **Upvote/downvote ratio** -- is this user a sycophant or a malcontent
- **Upvote/downvote ratio on answers to your questions** -- special case of above
- **Number of comments left**
- **Number of edits made**
- **Number of tags created**
- **Consecutive days visited the site**

I know from the previous discussions (linked above) some people will like some of these and find others useless.  Thoughts?

Comment: I am almost certain that I had an answer or question about this at one point where I gave a bunch of those as potential stats to track.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/new-user-rankings

Comment: Very similar, except you were asking for rankings and I'm just asking for the data.  I think lots of these stats are more innocuous if they are just on the profile page, if they were a basis for ranking it could rankle some folks (bad pun intended).

Comment: Oh I'm not saying they are dupes, just that I was looking at very similar tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Some other things that could be included.

- **Average comment vote**
- **Average rep per day**
- **Number of Closed Questions**
- **Open/Closed question ratio** - see the research value of the user
- **Number of Unaccepted Questions** - could be helpful for users that have asked a lot of questions
- **Page Views** - from different IP addresses
- **Page Views (2)** - includes views from IP addresses that have already visited
- **Total Amount of Time on SO** - this one is my personal fav. See how secluded people really are ;)
- **Total Amount of Questions Viewed**

In addition, there could also be a section of the page that contained personal user records. Some things that could be included

- **Highest Voted Question**
- **Highest Voted Answer**
- **Highest Voted Comment**
- **Lowest Voted Question**
- **Lowest Voted Answer**
- **Largest Rep Gain in a Day**
- **Largest Rep Loss in a Day**
- **Largest Amount of Questions in a Day**
- **Largest Amount of Answers in a Day**

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to include also **the number of questions favorited by other users**.

The reason is, number of questions favorited by others reflects how interesting your questions are to others, and should be something important.

By the way, if in the future our site does have the feature to [favorite an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/328421), please also include **the number of answers favorited by other users**.

Comment: "reflects how interesting your questions" can have different reasons and does not necessarily have a positive meaning. It can be used as "bookmarks"  for follow up e.g.

Comment: @bummi You are right, but in most cases, favoriting a question means it is worth coming back in some later time and in some ways reflects the interest on it.

Comment: Please, leave a message and tell me why you would downvote.